# We are experiencing various problems while attempting graphQL in the spring boot environment

Tags: graphql-java

I have a question during the project test for graph QL study.
I have two schema files: corporation.graphqls and member.graphqls.
However, corporation.graphqls does not work.
Fortunately, when the corporation.graphqls was generated first and then attempted, it was confirmed that the operation was performed normally, and the member.graphqls was also performed normally.
I think this problem occurs because more than one graphqls file exists together.
If it has to be integrated into one schema.graphqls file, I don't think it's possible to prevent the file from becoming congested as the number of modules increases.
In conclusion, I want to separate each *.graphqls for each module and make the function work.

In addition, can you process the return of ResponseEntity or PageImpl<> with graphQL?

I would like to convert the springboot + jpa + restapi project to graphQL.

Comment: I found a way.
In any file (.graphqls), you can specify it in the form of the previous extended type Query {}, extended type Mutation {} in the Query and Mutation settings.
In my opinion, in the existing state, both files are designated in root form, so one is overwritten.
I think one root query and root rotation were formed by adding extends.

Comment: Neat. Then add an actual answer to this question-post so it can be marked as "answered" :)